# Why my custom scrollbar not updating when jquery niceselect expands?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using jquery `mCustomScrollbar` and niceselect plugin. When I expand niceselect dropdown by clicking on it, `mCustomScrollbar` is not updating. I think, this is happening because of the absolute position of the dropdown list. But how can I fix this?

Here is the jsfiddle link:

https://jsfiddle.net/faridulhassan/u3zw09yr/

```
var $ = jQuery.noConflict(),
wrapper = $('.wrapper');
$('select').niceSelect();
wrapper.mCustomScrollbar();
```

Comment: If you inspect the DOM you can see that `overflow: hidden` is the cause of the issue. It's being applied to the `.mCustomScrollBox` and `.mCSB_container` elements through the `jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css` file. You would need to remove/override those settings - although my guess is this will break the functionality of the dropdown

Comment: You problem is that when you expand your second DDL, scroll is not increasing. Am I correct?

Comment: yes @SarinJacobSunny you are right

Comment: yes, @SarinJacobSunny.

Comment: In that fiddler, it is not working, but when I copied your code into an html, it is working fine, check it'

Comment: @SarinJacobSunny, could you provide your html please or any js fiddle?

Comment: I added it as an answer below

Answer (score 0):

When I tried your fiddler, the problem was there.

But when I copied this code into an HTML, look like it is working.

Posting it as an answer, as there is this is the easy way to share code.

Copy this to an html and try. I think that was a limitation in fiddler. Let us know the results.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/3.1.5/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-nice-select/1.1.0/css/nice-select.min.css">
        <style>
            body {
                overflow: hidden;
            }

            .wrapper {
                height: 100vh;
            }

            .mCSB_dragger_bar {
                background-color: #988f01 !important;
            }
            .nice-select {
                float: none;
                .list {
                    width: 100%;
                }
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore, porro voluptatibus accusantium saepe dolor, numquam, debitis magnam consequatur ullam quaerat laudantium pariatur suscipit, ratione odio libero dicta deleniti! Adipisci, vero.
            </p>
            <div>
                <select name="" id="">
                    <option value="">option 1</option>
                    <option value="">option 2</option>
                    <option value="">option 3</option>
                    <option value="">option 4</option>
                    <option value="">option 5</option>
                    <option value="">option 6</option>
                    <option value="">option 7</option>
                    <option value="">option 8</option>
                    <option value="">option 9</option>
                    <option value="">option 10</option>
                    <option value="">option 11</option>
                    <option value="">option 12</option>
                    <option value="">option 13</option>
                    <option value="">option 14</option>
                    <option value="">option 15</option>
                    <option value="">option 16</option>
                    <option value="">option 17</option>
                    <option value="">option 18</option>
                    <option value="">option 19</option>
                    <option value="">option 20</option>
                    <option value="">option 21</option>
                    <option value="">option 22</option>
                    <option value="">option 23</option>
                    <option value="">option 24</option>
                    <option value="">option 25</option>
                    <option value="">option 26</option>
                    <option value="">option 27</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore, porro voluptatibus accusantium saepe dolor, numquam, debitis magnam consequatur ullam quaerat laudantium pariatur suscipit, ratione odio libero dicta deleniti! Adipisci, vero.
            </p>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore, porro voluptatibus accusantium saepe dolor, numquam, debitis magnam consequatur ullam quaerat laudantium pariatur suscipit, ratione odio libero dicta deleniti! Adipisci, vero.
            </p>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore, porro voluptatibus accusantium saepe dolor, numquam, debitis magnam consequatur ullam quaerat laudantium pariatur suscipit, ratione odio libero dicta deleniti! Adipisci, vero.
            </p>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore, porro voluptatibus accusantium saepe dolor, numquam, debitis magnam consequatur ullam quaerat laudantium pariatur suscipit, ratione odio libero dicta deleniti! Adipisci, vero.
            </p>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore, porro voluptatibus accusantium saepe dolor, numquam, debitis magnam consequatur ullam quaerat laudantium pariatur suscipit, ratione odio libero dicta deleniti! Adipisci, vero.
            </p>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore, porro voluptatibus accusantium saepe dolor, numquam, debitis magnam consequatur ullam quaerat laudantium pariatur suscipit, ratione odio libero dicta deleniti! Adipisci, vero.
            </p>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore, porro voluptatibus accusantium saepe dolor, numquam, debitis magnam consequatur ullam quaerat laudantium pariatur suscipit, ratione odio libero dicta deleniti! Adipisci, vero.
            </p>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore, porro voluptatibus accusantium saepe dolor, numquam, debitis magnam consequatur ullam quaerat laudantium pariatur suscipit, ratione odio libero dicta deleniti! Adipisci, vero.
            </p>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore, porro voluptatibus accusantium saepe dolor, numquam, debitis magnam consequatur ullam quaerat laudantium pariatur suscipit, ratione odio libero dicta deleniti! Adipisci, vero.
            </p>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore, porro voluptatibus accusantium saepe dolor, numquam, debitis magnam consequatur ullam quaerat laudantium pariatur suscipit, ratione odio libero dicta deleniti! Adipisci, vero.
            </p>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore, porro voluptatibus accusantium saepe dolor, numquam, debitis magnam consequatur ullam quaerat laudantium pariatur suscipit, ratione odio libero dicta deleniti! Adipisci, vero.
            </p>
            <div>
                <select name="" id="">
                    <option value="">option 1</option>
                    <option value="">option 2</option>
                    <option value="">option 3</option>
                    <option value="">option 4</option>
                    <option value="">option 5</option>
                    <option value="">option 6</option>
                    <option value="">option 7</option>
                    <option value="">option 8</option>
                    <option value="">option 9</option>
                    <option value="">option 10</option>
                    <option value="">option 11</option>
                    <option value="">option 12</option>
                    <option value="">option 13</option>
                    <option value="">option 14</option>
                    <option value="">option 15</option>
                    <option value="">option 16</option>
                    <option value="">option 17</option>
                    <option value="">option 18</option>
                    <option value="">option 19</option>
                    <option value="">option 20</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-nice-select/1.1.0/js/jquery.nice-select.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/3.1.5/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script>



        <script>
            var $ = jQuery.noConflict(),
                    wrapper = $('.wrapper');
            $('select').niceSelect();
            wrapper.mCustomScrollbar({
                mouseWheelPixels: 200,
                scrollInertia: 100,
                callbacks: {
                    onScrollStart: function () {},
                    onInit: function () {},
                    onOverflowY: function () {}
                },
                mouseWheel: {
                    preventDefault: false
                }
            });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what exactly is the issue you are noticing now/

Comment: I wanted to update my container height when I expand dropdown list  and mcustomscrollbar need to update scroll height. so that all dropdown list is visible / scrollable. But it's not working yet. Please expand the 2nd dropdown list below of the page for better understanding.